# Python re not working with requests' POST response

Tags: regex, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm extracting data from a website using Python `requests` and I've run into a strange problem.
I'm using `re` with the response from my post requests to extract some table data like this:

```py
import re
import requests

tables = re.compile(r'^\s*(<table width.*?table>)$', flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
with open(tableInfoFile, fileSaveFormat) as f:
    chartInfoPage = session.post(tableURL, headers=postLoginHeaders, data=data, verify=False)
    for table in re.findall(tables, chartInfoPage.content.decode('utf-8'), flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE):
        f.write(table)
```

However this doesn't write anything! I've already tested the regex and it works perfectly when i use it directly on the response data(copied from the browser).
What's even stranger is that this code works just fine too:

```py
import re
import requests

tables = re.compile(r'^\s*(<table width.*?table>)$', flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
with open(tableInfoFile, fileSaveFormat) as f:
    chartInfoPage = session.post(tableURL, headers=postLoginHeaders, data=data, verify=False)
    with open('test.html', 'w') as temp:
        temp.write(chartInfoPage.content.decode('utf-8'))
    with open('test.html', 'r') as temp:
        data = temp.read()
    for table in re.findall(tables, data, flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE):
        f.write(table)
```

This makes no sense to me. All I'm doing is saving the data to a file and then just reading it. How is this any different from using the data directly??
Thanks in advance.

Edit: Oh and here's an example of the table data I'm trying to extract if it helps:

```html
<table width="100%" class="contentTable" cellpading=3>
<tr>
<td colspan=12 class="header">لیست دروس ارایه شده توسط دانشکده مهندسی عمران</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="header" ><nobr> شماره درس</nobr></td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>گروه</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>واحد</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>نام درس</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>پيشنياز و همنياز</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>ظرفيت</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>تعداد ثبت نامی</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>نام استاد</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>تاريخ امتحان</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>برنامه هفتگی</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>ملاحظات</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>پیغام به هنگام ثبت نام</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td  class="contentCell"><nobr>10021</td>
    <td  class="contentCell"><nobr>1</td>
    <td  class="contentCell"><nobr>1</td>
    <td  class="contentCell"><nobr>آز هیدرولیک</td>
    <td  class="contentCell" width=150>پيشنياز: 13410: 13110</td>
    <td class = "contentCell"><nobr><span dir="ltr"> 16</span></font></td>
    <td class="contentCell" ><nobr> &nbsp;</font></td>
    <td class="contentCell" width=150>Crossed out</font></td>
    <td  class="contentCell"><nobr><span dir=ltr>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    <td  class="contentCell"><nobr> شنبه  8:0 تا 12:0 شنبه  13:0 تا 15:0</td>
    <td  class="contentCell">برگزاری این درس فقط با شرط ثبت نام قطعی حداقل 15 نفر امکان پذیر است 
    </td>
    <td  class="contentCell">برگزاری این درس فقط با شرط ثبت نام قطعی حداقل 15 نفر امکان پذیر است</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to pull out/parse html, BeautifulSoup is the way to go. In this particular case, you have `<table>` tags.

```
html = '''<table width="100%" class="contentTable" cellpading=3>
<tr>
<td colspan=12 class="header">لیست دروس ارایه شده توسط دانشکده مهندسی عمران</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="header" ><nobr> شماره درس</nobr></td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>گروه</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>واحد</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>نام درس</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>پيشنياز و همنياز</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>ظرفيت</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>تعداد ثبت نامی</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>نام استاد</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>تاريخ امتحان</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>برنامه هفتگی</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>ملاحظات</td>
    <td class="header" ><nobr>پیغام به هنگام ثبت نام</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td  class="contentCell"><nobr>10021</td>
    <td  class="contentCell"><nobr>1</td>
    <td  class="contentCell"><nobr>1</td>
    <td  class="contentCell"><nobr>آز هیدرولیک</td>
    <td  class="contentCell" width=150>پيشنياز: 13410: 13110</td>
    <td class = "contentCell"><nobr><span dir="ltr"> 16</span></font></td>
    <td class="contentCell" ><nobr> &nbsp;</font></td>
    <td class="contentCell" width=150>Crossed out</font></td>
    <td  class="contentCell"><nobr><span dir=ltr>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    <td  class="contentCell"><nobr> شنبه  8:0 تا 12:0 شنبه  13:0 تا 15:0</td>
    <td  class="contentCell">برگزاری این درس فقط با شرط ثبت نام قطعی حداقل 15 نفر امکان پذیر است 
    </td>
    <td  class="contentCell">برگزاری این درس فقط با شرط ثبت نام قطعی حداقل 15 نفر امکان پذیر است</td>
  </tr>
</table>'''
```

The `.find_all('table')` will store a list of the elements with the `<table>` tag. It's then just a matter of selecting the table you want by index, or just iterate through the list of elements and print it out, write it to file, do what you would like with it:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

tables = soup.find_all('table')


for table in tables:
    print (table)
```

Comment: well I don't really want to extract the data, I just want to save the data directly to an ```html``` file and upload it to a website. ```re``` is just so much easier to do this with.

Comment: ah ok, wel than as I stated before, simply use beautiful soup to pull out the `<table>` tag elements. I updated the solution.

Comment: I ended up doing just that, turns out using ```re``` with ```^``` and ```$``` regular expressions doesn't work on post responses. To anyone else that doesn't want to use ```BeautifulSoup```, i suggest just finding out a way to remove those 2 characters in their regex.